# Syntax error in UPDATE statement in ASP.NET using C# with Access Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I'm getting a "Syntax error in UPDATE statement" error when I run the following Access statements. How do I get past that?

This is the relevant portion of my web page code.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Prasat PVS\\Documents\\db.mdb";

    string q1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE password ='" + TextBox1.Text + "'";

    string q2 = "UPDATE users SET password='"+TextBox2.Text+"' WHERE password='"+TextBox1.Text+"'";

    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connect))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q1, con))
        {
            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                using (OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection(connect))
                {
                    con1.Open();

                    using (OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(q2, con1))
                    {
                        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    Label1.Text = "Your Password Has Been Changed Successfully";

                    con1.Close();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "Your Password Is Incorrect Try Again";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First off, your application is vulnerable to SQL injection -- use parameterized queries. Secondly, storing plaintext passwords is a **terrible** thing to do. And just to point out a logic flaw: What if two users have the same password? Your current logic will change the password of every user that shares the original password.

Comment: In addition to those other issues, I'm not sure I understand why you're nesting your update inside the select. Your `q1` is used only to test whether the user exists, but your update will already do that. This just ties up resources and acts as a huge waste of network.

Comment: Also, this one is less serious, but why are you not making use of ASP's built in authentication platform? I'm not sure about with Identity, but certainly with anything before you could use Forms authentication to override behavior and match your database. Although with Azure offering something like twenty MB free of real SQL, that's a much better option than Access for a web service.

Comment: `"UPDATE users SET password='"+TextBox2.Text+"' WHERE password='"+TextBox1.Text+"'"` Is this real life? Or is this fantasy? What if two users share the same password?

Answer (score 1):

maybe the problem is because you have used password as name for password field... instead use pass or something other

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that your password has an apostrophe in it. If that's the case, you'll have something like `UPDATE users SET password = 'pass'word'...` which is pretty clearly the wrong syntax. That's the most likely thing I can see that could be causing an error like that.

Yet another point to parameterizing your queries...

And while you're at it, I mentioned this in a comment, but you'd be much better to only run one query (your update, after you add in a check for the username) and check the result of `ExecuteNonQuery` to know whether any rows were affected (the password changed successfully) or not (the username or password was incorrect).

Comment: else give some suggestion to improve my code for change password option with out using change password control in .net ......

Comment: I think you've got the start down, you just need to alter your implementation a bit. It sounds like other people have given you some good starting points. You should start by adding a test in your `WHERE` clause to check the username before changing the password. You should also implement query parameterization, and there are lots of examples of that around. Then it should work perfectly for you.